# Let $ G $ be a group and $ N \lhd G $. Why is $G $ supersoluble if $ N $ is cyclic and $ G/N $ is supersoluble?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, quotient-group

Let $ G $ be a group and $ N \lhd G $. If $ N $ and $ G/N $ are soluble, then $ G $ is a soluble group. But it is not true for supersoluble groups. Why is $G $ supersoluble if $ N $ is cyclic and $ G/N $ is supersoluble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $G/N$ is supersolvable, there is a normal series
$$
\{N\} = H_0 \triangleleft H_1 \triangleleft \cdots \triangleleft H_{s-1} \triangleleft H_s = G/N
$$
with all quotients $H_{i+1}/H_i$ cyclic.

By the [correspondence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_theorem_%28group_theory%29) the normal subgroups of $G/N$ correspond to normal subgroups of $G$ containing $N$, so each $H_i$ is uniquely determined by some normal subgroup $N_i\supseteq N$ as $H_i = N_i/N$. By the third isomorphism theorem the quotients are
$$
H_{i+1}/H_i = (N_{i+1}/N)/(N_i/N) \cong N_{i+1}/N_i.
$$
So the successive quotients of the $N_i$ are again cyclic. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I have a feeling the OP is using the "stronger" definition of supersolvable, requiring not just cyclic, but abelian simple quotients, which makes this slightly harder (and essentially an exercise in showing that the definitions are equivalent).

Comment: Then there is a normal series $  1 = N_{0} \lhd N_{1} \lhd \cdots \lhd N_{i-1} \lhd N_{i} = G $ of $ G $ with all quotients $ N_{i+1}/N_{i} $ cyclic. Hence $ G $ is supersoluble.